# Symfony2 joined data passed to View

Tags: symfony, join, twig

I'm passing some data to a view which has been joined. The join is working correctly, because I can see the number of results changing based on whether I choose join or leftJoin. My query is this:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->join('p.skill', 's')
        ->getQuery();

$people2 = $query->getResult();

return $this->render('StudioRaygunTeamBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('people2' => $people2));
```

And my view:

```
<ul>
  {% for person in people2 %}
    <li>{{ person.firstname }} {{ person.surname }}
        {% for skill in person.skill %}
            {{ skill.skillname }}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

No errors are thrown, unless I change some of the values inside the curly braces - this implies that the data being fetched is correct (it is, and it matches up with the entity classes).

But nothing outputs under skill.skillname (person.firstname etc appears fine!).

If I try to do a dump() I just get a blank screen and PHP memory error, which is annoying, so I can't debug.

So to wrap up - my data is correct (no errors) and my syntax, from what I've read, is also correct - but no data is returned for skill.skillname (person.firstname etc appear as expected).

Comment: Are the skill names set?

Answer (score 1):

### Selecting joins:

You also need to select the entities you join:

```
 $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->addSelect('s')
    ->join('p.skill', 's')
    ->getQuery();
```

### Dumps:

Variables populated by Doctrine2 are Proxy classes for your own entity classes and they have references to Doctrine2 internals. In these cases recursion is imminent. And with recursion you'll always hit the memory limit.

Because of this there are several approaches to debugging such as using xdebug or zend debugger to inspect the actual data.

Comment: That throws a 500 error - /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php line 140

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Team in /Users/mattsaunders/Documents/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php line 140

Comment: Did you register your bundle in `config.yml` unde the `doctrine.orm` subsections?

Comment: I haven't added anything to config.yml but I did generate all the required parts through the command line...

Comment: just to confirm - person.firstname etc are appearing correctly!

Comment: Oh if those are looking good then the Doctrine registration should be OK.

Comment: Does your entity declare a property called team which the SQL table doesn't have?

Comment: no, both tables exist and have relational data. it's just my view that won't show it for some reason - can you confirm that the syntax correct?

Comment: Yes it looks pretty much OK but I can't know all other files (entity classes etc.).